# SAPUI5- How to hide a button/region/area when a button is pressed?

Tags: sapui5

I want to hide a button/area/region(header,footer,etc) when a button is clicked. How can I achieve this?
For example if I have the following page:

```
   <mvc:View
     height="100%"
     xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
   xmlns="sap.m">
     <Page
         title="Hide Area On Button Click" >
             <content>
             <Button  id="btn1" text="Accept" type="Accept" press="onPress" />
             <Button id="btn2" text="Reject" type="Reject" />
          </content>
          <footer>

          </footer>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Now what should be the

```
onPress : function {//code}
```

to hide the reject button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code should accomplish that:

```
 onPress:function(oEvent) {
        var rejectBtn = this.getView().byId("btn2");
        if(rejectBtn.getVisible()) {
           rejectBtn.setVisible(false);
       }
    }
```